# Galaxy Note 3 Uses Normal Layout Instead of Large Layout

Tags: android, screen

I am about to finish my app however I have been struggling with screen size differences. I run the code both on **Galaxy S** and **Galaxy Note 3**.

Although *Note 3* has a screen 5.7" with `1080x1920 resolution`, it takes the layout from the folder under res, layout-normal.

How I can solve this problem?

EDIT: Here are some screenshots from devices and Eclipse:

http://prntscr.com/36qmsv - This is from the file sw600dp\activity_main.xml

http://prntscr.com/36qnci - This is from the file sw720dp\activity_main.xml

http://prntscr.com/36qnkc - This is from the file activity_main.xml (layout folder)

http://prntscr.com/36qo1i - This is from Samsung Galaxy S

http://prntscr.com/36qo9a - This is from Samsung Galaxy Note 3

Comment: please put a picture from your app.your question is not clear enough for me

Comment: I have edited the question @Salman, you can check the images.